# How to troubleshoot an infinite loop in a Python script?

Tags: python

Why is this forming an infinite loop?
in this code can anybody tell me why this is forming an infinite loop,
is it because the "x" variable is initialized using the wrong value or does it need to have parameters passed to the function.

this should print 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

```
def count_to_ten():
  x = 1
  while x <= 10:
    print(x)
    x = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

X is assigned to 1 and never incremented, providing an infinite loop.

```
def count_to_ten():
x = 1
while x <= 10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

This will increment x after each loop and print your expected answer

Answer (score 0):

So You have assigned `x` as `1`. And when the loop runs it checks if `x` is less than or equals `10`.
But inside the loop, you never change the loop's [counter variable](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-a-%E2%80%9Ccounter-variable%E2%80%9D-in-a-for-loop)(`x`). So the condition won't become false. So the result is an infinite loop.

So you have to change the counter variable x inside the loop where the loop condition becomes false after the desired number of iterations.

```
def count_to_ten():
  x = 1
  while x <= 10:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```